# Json object extraction from multiple objects using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, data-structures, data-manipulation

I'm getting json data from REST API having the structure below. The data provides me a list of data having dict structure and having ids. I want to access specific data just by using the id e.g `data['x1234']`. But I couldn't because each time I have to iterate over the list and checking ids or ending having sth like this `data["body"][0]["id"]`. How can I solve the issue?

```
{
body:
    [{
        id: x1234,
        name: a1,
        ....
    },
    {
        id: b1234,
        name: b1,
        ....
    }]
}
```

I just want to extract particular object with id having a value b1234 so data["b1234"] returns the following output:

```
{
 id: b1234,
 name: b1,
 ....
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Also, *why is that the file to start with*, rather than e.g. serialising a single JSON *array*?

Comment: I'm getting json data from REST API, with above structure, I have used urllib to extract the json data, i'm unable to find syntax to extract the contents with key=value

Comment: That doesn't really answer either of my questions. Is that the result of *multiple REST calls* (in which case you need to rethink how *you're* storing them) or of a single call (in which case you need to complain to whoever maintains the service that they're returning broken JSON)?

Comment: If it is about extracting the data from JSON using Python you may want to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13633860/6573902).

Comment: yes, it is just extract the data with particular id, if I use ` data["body"][0]["id"] ` it is listing value of index 0, is there a way I can mention index value which contains the id value as b1234

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Comment: how can I condition it to extract only single object which  has value of b1234

Comment: "I have json file with multiple nested objects". This can never happen. Ask the source to fix this.

Comment: @LutzHorn  is the incorrect json format which i'm getting from REST API ?: `{
body:
[ {
id:x1234
name:a1
  { 
   version:123
   appname:abc
  }
},
{
 id:b1234
 name:b1
  {
   appname:testapp
   subapp:test2
  }
 }]
}
`

Comment: This is not valid JSON because you must use double quotes `"`. But the structure looks OK.

Comment: It's also missing commas and keys for the nested objects, so yeah, that's not valid JSON at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build new dict structure from the list using the id as dict key as follow:

```
items_list = json_data['body']
items_dict = {item['id']: item for item in items_list}
```

Then you can access specific data using the id value as follow:

```
print(items_dict['b1234'])
```